How can I send ImgUrl to Twitter(X)?
enter image description hereThis only shows Url. But I want to show Img too.
      dialog_news_twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tweetUrl = String.format("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%s&url=%s", URLEncoder.encode(newsData.getNewsUrl()));
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(tweetUrl));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

I tried this... but don't know how to send imgUrl and show it like that image.

I think it might be better to use Twitter's API to upload media: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload
